# Perform a left join based on one to multiple rows in both tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

One table contains codes representing parts of surgical operations. One procedure is described by one ore more codes (one row per code). Combinations of procedures may occure. One operation may e.g.consist of 1 procedure represented by one code and a second procedure represented by 3 codes (4 rows for this operation).

A left join has to be performed with a second table containing the codes for the procedures with one or many codes each in one row.

Of note, a certain code used to describe a procedure based on a total of three codes may also occure as a single code describing a different procedure like the last entry in table #Procedures. Hence, a simple join does not solve the problem.

In the present solution I use two nested while statement taking hours in SQL Server 2014. Is there a more efficiant way to perform this task, maybe using the xml functionality of SQL Server?

Any help appreciated.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Procedures 
(
    ProcID INT, 
    NumberofCodes INT, 
    Codes NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Procedures (ProcID, NumberofCodes, Codes) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'SingleCodeXYZ'), (2, 3, 'TripleCodeXY1'), (2, 3, 'TripleCodeXY2'),
       (2, 3, 'TripleCodeXY3'), (3, 2, 'DoubleCodeXY1'), (3, 2, 'DoubleCodeXY2'),
       (4, 1, 'SingleCodeABC'), (5, 1, 'TripleCodeXY2')

CREATE TABLE #KodesforOperations 
(
    OPID INT, 
    ProcID INT, 
    NumberofCodes INT, 
    Codes NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #KodesforOperations (OPID, NumberofCodes, Codes) 
VALUES (1, 4, 'SingleCodeXYZ'), (1, 4, 'TripleCodeXY1'), (1, 4, 'TripleCodeXY2'), 
       (1, 4, 'TripleCodeXY3'),
       (2, 1, 'SingleCodeABC'),
       (3, 2, 'DoubleCodeXY1'), (3, 2, 'DoubleCodeXY2')

--SELECT * FROM #Procedures
--SELECT * FROM #KodesforOperations

--nested While statements:
UPDATE A 
SET A.ProcID = B.ProcID 
FROM #KodesforOperations A 
LEFT JOIN #Procedures B On A.Codes = B.Codes
WHERE A.NumberofCodes >= 3 AND B.NumberofCodes >= 3

UPDATE A 
SET A.ProcID = B.ProcID 
FROM #KodesforOperations A 
LEFT JOIN #Procedures B On A.Codes = B.Codes
WHERE A.NumberofCodes >= 2 AND B.NumberofCodes >= 2

UPDATE A 
SET A.ProcID = B.ProcID 
FROM #KodesforOperations A 
LEFT JOIN #Procedures B On A.Codes = B.Codes
WHERE A.NumberofCodes >= 1 AND B.NumberofCodes >= 1

SELECT * FROM #KodesforOperations
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to combine the conditions.  However, this is logically equivalent to just checking the third:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.ProcID = B.ProcID 
    FROM #KodesforOperations A JOIN
         #Procedures B
         On A.Codes = B.Codes
WHERE A.NumberofCodes >= 1 AND B.NumberofCodes >= 1;
```

If this condition is true, then the comparisons to `2` and `3` are also true.

The `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary, because you need a match in the two tables to test the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Dear Gordon, thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately, when doing so the last entry in table #Procedures with code 'TripleCodeXY2' which also is part of the combination of three codes representing the procedure with ProcID = 3 might be joined to the operation with OPID = 1 which instead should be joined with the three codes with ProcID = 2.

Comment: @ReneW . . . That may be the case, but this logic is equivalent to what is in your question.  Perhaps that is not the logic you really need.

Comment: Thanks, have updated the description of the problem.